# Is there an alternative to reshape2::melt for multidimensional arrays in base R or tidyverse?

Tags: r, arrays, tidyr, reshape2

Suppose I have a 3-dimensional array `g` with dimensions `[x,y,z]`. `reshape2::melt(g)` would produce a data frame with columns giving indices of `x,y,z` and `value` where `value` contains the values in each entry of the prior array.

Given that `reshape2` is [superseded](https://github.com/hadley/reshape), is there a "one function" alternative to the functionality of `reshape2::melt` in base R or a more actively supported `tidyverse` package that I'm missing?

`reshape2` recommends people use `tidyr` instead but I can't seem to find solutions to multi-dimensional arrays in `tidyr`. There is [cubelyr](https://github.com/hadley/cubelyr) but doesn't seem like that is very active these days either.

I can write a custom solution, just looking for something stable with the easy functionality of `reshape2::melt` for this kind of problem

```r
library(reshape2)

g_as_array <- array(rnorm(9), dim = c(3,3,3)) # create a 3D array

g_as_data_frame <- reshape2::melt(g_as_array) # melt down to "tidy" format

head(g_as_data_frame)
#>   Var1 Var2 Var3      value
#> 1    1    1    1  1.4092362
#> 2    2    1    1 -2.1606972
#> 3    3    1    1  0.4334404
#> 4    1    2    1  0.2390544
#> 5    2    2    1 -0.9673617
#> 6    3    2    1  0.5668378
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Base approach and data.table answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63311405/seeking-r-function-to-melt-5-dimensional-array-like-pivot-longer  `as.data.frame(ftable(g_as_array))` or `data.table::as.data.table(g_as_array)`

Comment: That's great, thank you. For the base approach would just need to convert factor labels back to numeric indices then e.g. `as.data.frame(ftable(g_as_array)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(dplyr::starts_with("Var"), as.numeric))`

Comment: `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` from tidyr seem to be the main alternatives these days.

Comment: True in general but `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` only work for two-dimensional table-like data, not multi-dimensional arrays, unless I'm missing some functionality there?

Comment: An ideal answer would preserve dimnames if they existed

Comment: `as.data.frame.table(g_as_array)` will give the results but using `LETTERS` instead of `numbers`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a <- array(1:27, dim = c(3,3,3))

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(a)

DF2 <- data.frame(
  expand.grid(lapply(dim(a), seq_len)),
  value = as.vector(a)
)

identical(DF1, DF2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If the array has dimension names:

```
a <-array(letters[1:27], dim = c(3, 3, 3), dimnames = list(letters[1:3],
                                                           letters[4:6],
                                                           letters[7:9]))

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(a)
    
DF2 <- data.frame(
  expand.grid(dimnames(a)),
  value = as.vector(a)
)

identical(DF1, DF2)
#[1] TRUE
```

If not all dimensions have names, you would need to fill in the missing names first, e.g.:

```
Map(\(x, y) if (is.null(x)) seq_len(y) else x , dimnames(a), dim(a))
```

Comment: Nice solution! +1! I think you can use `expand.grid(lapply(dim(g),seq.int))` without any `do.call`, i.e., `cbind(expand.grid(lapply(dim(g), seq.int)), value = c(g))`

Comment: Thanks, I always forget that. Luckily, the overhead from `do.call` is minimal.

Comment: And I remember a BDR fortune quote regarding misuse of `c` to strip attributes.

Answer (score 7):

An option would be to use `arrayInd`.

```
A <- array(1:8, c(2,2,2))

data.frame(arrayInd(seq_along(A), dim(A)), value = as.vector(A))
#  X1 X2 X3 value
#1  1  1  1     1
#2  2  1  1     2
#3  1  2  1     3
#4  2  2  1     4
#5  1  1  2     5
#6  2  1  2     6
#7  1  2  2     7
#8  2  2  2     8
```

Or quite similar to @ThomasIsCoding using `which`.

```
data.frame(which(array(TRUE, dim(A)), arr.ind = TRUE), value = as.vector(A))
#  dim1 dim2 dim3 value
#1    1    1    1     1
#2    2    1    1     2
#3    1    2    1     3
#4    2    2    1     4
#5    1    1    2     5
#6    2    1    2     6
#7    1    2    2     7
#8    2    2    2     8
```

If the array has dimension names.

```
A <- array(1:8, c(2,2,2), list(X=c("a","b"), Y=c("c","d"), Z=c("e","f")))

i <- arrayInd(seq_along(A), dim(A), dimnames(A), TRUE)
data.frame(mapply(`[`, dimnames(A), asplit(i, 2)), value = as.vector(A))
#  X Y Z value
#1 a c e     1
#2 b c e     2
#3 a d e     3
#4 b d e     4
#5 a c f     5
#6 b c f     6
#7 a d f     7
#8 b d f     8
```

But this can be achieved, as shown in the comments, with  `as.data.frame(ftable(A))` @Jon Spring or `as.data.frame.table(A)` @Onyambu.
If you look at the source of `as.data.frame.table` you see that it is using `expand.grid`.

```
as.data.frame.table(A)    #@Onyambu.
#as.data.frame(ftable(A)) #@Jon Spring
#  X Y Z Freq
#1 a c e    1
#2 b c e    2
#3 a d e    3
#4 b d e    4
#5 a c f    5
#6 b c f    6
#7 a d f    7
#8 b d f    8
```

But if *numeric indices* are wanted this can be used.

```
sapply(as.data.frame.table(A), unclass)
#     X Y Z Freq
#[1,] 1 1 1    1
#[2,] 2 1 1    2
#[3,] 1 2 1    3
#[4,] 2 2 1    4
#[5,] 1 1 2    5
#[6,] 2 1 2    6
#[7,] 1 2 2    7
#[8,] 2 2 2    8
```

Or more robust and giving a `data.frame`:

```
tt <- as.data.frame.table(A)
tt[-length(tt)] <- lapply(tt[-length(tt)], unclass)
tt
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
#1    1    1    1    1
#2    2    1    1    2
#3    1    2    1    3
#4    2    2    1    4
#5    1    1    2    5
#6    2    1    2    6
#7    1    2    2    7
#8    2    2    2    8

#or
list2DF(lapply(as.data.frame.table(A), unclass))
```

Or a variant - Thanks to @Onyambu for the hint!

```
type.convert(as.data.frame.table(`dimnames<-`(A, NULL),
             base = list(as.character(seq_len(max(dim(A)))))), as.is = TRUE)
#  Var1 Var2 Var3 Freq
#1    1    1    1    1
#2    2    1    1    2
#3    1    2    1    3
#4    2    2    1    4
#5    1    1    2    5
#6    2    1    2    6
#7    1    2    2    7
#8    2    2    2    8
```

Another option is to calculate it "by hand" with `%%` and `%/%`.

```
cbind(1 + mapply(`%%`,
    Reduce(`%/%`, dim(A)[-length(dim(A))], 0:(length(A)-1), accumulate = TRUE),
    dim(A)), Value=as.vector(A))
#           Value
#[1,] 1 1 1     1
#[2,] 2 1 1     2
#[3,] 1 2 1     3
#[4,] 2 2 1     4
#[5,] 1 1 2     5
#[6,] 2 1 2     6
#[7,] 1 2 2     7
#[8,] 2 2 2     8

#Alternative
. <- 0:(length(A)-1)
cbind(1 +
    t(t(cbind(., outer(., cumprod(dim(A)[-length(dim(A))]), `%/%`))) %% dim(A)),
    Value=A)
```

or using `rep`.

```
list2DF(c(Map(\(i, j, n) rep(rep(1:i, each=j), length.out=n),
    dim(A),
    c(1, cumprod(dim(A)[-length(dim(A))])),
    length(A)), Value=list(as.vector(A))))
#        Value
#1 1 1 1     1
#2 2 1 1     2
#3 1 2 1     3
#4 2 2 1     4
#5 1 1 2     5
#6 2 1 2     6
#7 1 2 2     7
#8 2 2 2     8
```

Or basically the same but keeping names and make use of auto repetition.

```
d <- setNames(dim(A), names(dimnames(A)))
do.call(data.frame, c(
  Map(\(i,j) rep(1:i, each=j), d, c(1, cumprod(d[-length(d)]))),
  Value=list(as.vector(A) ), fix.empty.names = FALSE) )
  X Y Z Value
1 1 1 1     1
2 2 1 1     2
3 1 2 1     3
4 2 2 1     4
5 1 1 2     5
6 2 1 2     6
7 1 2 2     7
8 2 2 2     8
```

---

Benchmark

```
A <- array(0, c(1e5, 12, 30), list(T=NULL, Month=NULL, Year=NULL))

bench::mark(check=FALSE,
reshape2 = reshape2::melt(A),
expand.grid = {data.frame(  #@Roland
  expand.grid(lapply(dim(A), seq_len)),
  value = as.vector(A)) },
data.frame.table = {tt <- as.data.frame.table(A)
  tt[-length(tt)] <- lapply(tt[-length(tt)], unclass)
  tt},
rep = {d <- setNames(dim(A), names(dimnames(A)))
do.call(data.frame, c(
  Map(\(i,j) rep(1:i, each=j), d, c(1, cumprod(d[-length(d)]))),
  Value=list(as.vector(A) ), fix.empty.names = FALSE) )} )
#  expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 reshape2            812ms    812ms      1.23    1.21GB     1.23     1     1
#2 expand.grid         733ms    733ms      1.36    1.21GB     2.73     1     2
#3 data.frame.table    605ms    605ms      1.65    1.23GB     3.31     1     2
#4 rep                 293ms    331ms      3.02  691.99MB     1.51     2     1
```

In this case the variant using `rep` is the fastest and allocates the lowest amount of memory.

Comment: also `data.frame(arrayInd(seq_along(A), dim(A)), value = c(A))`

Comment: Thanks! I had similar but instead of `c` with `as.vector`(see comment Roland in his answer) - see history of edits. But `arrayInd` "wants" a logical vector so I provide one.

Comment: Why would you say `arrayInd` wants a logical vector? `arrayInd` takes in an Integer valued vector. Not a logical vector. Please read the help page for array ind.

Comment: `sapply...unclass` is quite risky, I would suggest `type.convert(as.data.frame.table(A, base = list(as.character(1:20))), as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 4):

Here are some base R alternatives with the `which` trick that should work for general arrays, i.e., numeric and character:

1. `which(1^is.na(g) > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)`

```
cbind(as.data.frame(which(1^is.na(g) > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
```

2. `which(TRUE | is.na(g), arr.ind = TRUE)`

```
cbind(as.data.frame(which(TRUE | is.na(g), arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
```

3. `nchar(g, "width") > -1`

```
cbind(as.data.frame(which(nchar(g, "width") > -1, arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
```

and we will obtain

```
   dim1 dim2 dim3 value
1     1    1    1     a
2     2    1    1     b
3     3    1    1     c
4     1    2    1     d
5     2    2    1     e
6     3    2    1     f
7     1    3    1     g
8     2    3    1     h
9     3    3    1     i
10    1    1    2     j
11    2    1    2     k
12    3    1    2     l
13    1    2    2     m
14    2    2    2     n
15    3    2    2     o
16    1    3    2     p
17    2    3    2     q
18    3    3    2     r
19    1    1    3     s
20    2    1    3     t
21    3    1    3     u
22    1    2    3     v
23    2    2    3     w
24    3    2    3     x
25    1    3    3     y
26    2    3    3     z
27    3    3    3  <NA>
```

## Dummy Data

```
> (g <- array(letters[1:27], dim = c(3, 3, 3)))
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "d"  "g"
[2,] "b"  "e"  "h"
[3,] "c"  "f"  "i"

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "j"  "m"  "p"
[2,] "k"  "n"  "q"
[3,] "l"  "o"  "r"

, , 3

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "s"  "v"  "y"
[2,] "t"  "w"  "z"
[3,] "u"  "x"  NA
```

Comment: is `is.finite()` just a trick to get all of the elements? I guess I could define `isTRUE(x)` as `is.finite(x) | !is.finite(x)` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, I assume all entries are finite to play that trick. but yours is absolutely more generalized :)

Comment: @BenBolker Probably `^` is more efficient for numerical entries or `NA` or `Inf`.

Comment: You mean `^0` ?

Comment: @BenBolker I think both `1^g` and `g^0` should work

Comment: Based on minimal testing, looks like you're right. (Why would you prefer `1^g > 0` to `1^g == 1` or `as.logical(1^g)` ? fewer characters/code golfing?)

Comment: Solutions should work for any data type. Try yours with `(g <- array(letters[1:27], dim = c(3, 3, 3)))`

Comment: @Roland yes, you are right. then we can try `1^nchar(g)` instead

Comment: @BenBolker yes, I am used to code golfing.

Comment: @Roland But `nchar` won't work if there is `""`. Anyway, thanks for your feedback. I just assumed OP has numeric arrays so I played that trick.

Comment: @Roland I updated my solution with `1^is.na(g)`, which should fit for arrays with all types of entries.

Answer (score 3):

## Benchmarking, Just for Fun

Here are some interesting benchmarking observations for arrays of different dimensions (without considering the dimension names for simplifications), where multiple existing solutions to the posted questions are taken into account.

***Disclaimer***: We **DON'T** provide a conclusion which is the *"best"*, but you (not limited to the OP but for everyone that might need this sort of functionality, i.e., indexing of multi-dimensional arrays) have the degree of freedom to define the one suits your purpose best.

---

Below is the benchmarking function with respect to the dimension argument of a random array

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)

fbench <- function(dims) {
    # dummy data for test
    set.seed(0)
    g <- array(sample(prod(dims)), dim = dims)

    # list of approaches
    expgrd <- function() {
        data.frame(expand.grid(lapply(dim(g), seq_len)), value = as.vector(g))
    }

    arrind <- function() {
        data.frame(arrayInd(seq_along(g), dim(g)), value = as.vector(g))
    }

    which0 <- function() {
        data.frame(which(array(TRUE, dim(g)), arr.ind = TRUE), value = as.vector(g))
    }

    which1 <- function() {
        cbind(as.data.frame(which(1^is.na(g) > 0, arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
    }

    which2 <- function() {
        cbind(as.data.frame(which(TRUE | is.na(g), arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
    }

    which3 <- function() {
        cbind(as.data.frame(which(nchar(g, "width") > -1, arr.ind = TRUE)), value = c(g))
    }

    dftable0 <- function() {
        list2DF(lapply(as.data.frame.table(g), unclass))
    }

    dftable1 <- function() {
        list2DF(lapply(as.data.frame(ftable(g)), unclass))
    }

    dttable <- function() {
        as.data.table(g, sorted = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)
    }

    rem0 <- function() {
        as.data.frame(cbind(1 + mapply(
            `%%`,
            Reduce(`%/%`, dim(g)[-length(dim(g))], 0:(length(g) - 1), accumulate = TRUE),
            dim(g)
        ), Value = as.vector(g)))
    }

    rem1 <- function() {
        . <- 0:(length(g) - 1)
        as.data.frame(cbind(
            1 +
                t(t(cbind(., outer(., cumprod(dim(g)[-length(dim(g))]), `%/%`))) %% dim(g)),
            Value = g
        ))
    }

    reprep <- function() {
        list2DF(c(Map(
            \(i, j, n) rep(rep(1:i, each = j), length.out = n),
            dim(g),
            c(1, cumprod(dim(g)[-length(dim(g))])),
            length(g)
        ), Value = list(as.vector(g))))
    }

    # benchmarking module
    # benchmarking module
    mbm <- microbenchmark(
        expgrd(),
        arrind(),
        which0(),
        which1(),
        which2(),
        which3(),
        dftable0(),
        dftable1(),
        dttable(),
        rem0(),
        rem1(),
        reprep(),
        times = 50L,
        check = "equivalent"
    )

    boxplot(mbm, main = sprintf("dim = [%s]", toString(dims)), las = 2)
}
```

---

1. For `dim <- rep(5, 3)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]
2. For `dims <- rep(5, 4)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]
3. For `dims <- rep(5, 5)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]
4. For `dims <- rep(5, 6)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]
5. For `dims <- rep(5, 7)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]
6. For `dims <- rep(5, 8)`, we run `fbench(dims)` and obtain
   [image]

Comment: My takeaway from this would be "`dftable0` is usually pretty good"...

Comment: @BenBolker well...I would say that the size of array matters to the performance, where `dftable0` is always the middle-class regardless of the size :)

Comment: I guess (1) I don't expect this component to be a significant performance bottleneck (2) `dftable0` never seems to be *terrible* and (3) I prefer the `list2DF` solutions on aesthetic grounds  ...

Comment: Maybe you can add `reshape2::melt` and the variants using `%%` and `%/%` or `rep`?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, that's fair enough :)

Comment: @GKi yes, added. Interesting that `rep` has such a strong performance! Cool!

Comment: Thanks! Performance will change by size and might not be that important. But anyway nice comparison.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about adding the `rep`-based solution to `gtools` ...

Comment: @BenBolker Fine to read that my code will maybe be used in `gtools`!

Comment: Hmm. I thought these would all preserve dimnames but apparently `reprep` doesn't ... ??

Comment: @BenBolker Nope. none of the approaches for this benchmark will preserve the dimension names.

Comment: I think that's not true - `a <- array(1:8, dim  = c(2,2,2), dimnames=list(d1 = letters[1:2], d2 = LETTERS[1:2], d3 = c("x", "y"))); as.data.frame.table(a)` is built-in, is never worst, and preserves dimnames and dimname-names ...

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, you are right on that point. However, in this benchmark, I enforce all approaches to have an uniform output for the fair comparison, i.e., integer indexing manner, instead of dimension names. That's why `as.data.frame.table(a)` is followed by `unclass` in my benchmarking script.